# Why I select inherit global site-packages on Pycharm, nothing happened?

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I select inherit global site-packages on Pycharm when I create a new project. But there is no site-packages I downloaded before under the path of my base interpreter in my new project.

e.g. The path of my pandas lib is

"D:\python\Lib\site-packages\pandas",

but there is no pandas lib in

"D:\pycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages".

Is this normal?

I copy and paste the pandas lib, and it worked. I also install packages through the way Pycharm gave, it worked too. So is it necessary to copy and paste after I select inherit global site-packages, or I just miss some steps?

Comment: you probably have more than one python interpreter and the one used for creating new venv is not the one with pandas installed. What is the path to the base python interpreter in pycharm?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The path of my base python interpreter is "D:\python\python.exe"

Comment: I try it on the another computer, and it worked. I think it might be the problem of my environment variables, I am gonna try to fix it.